# Ignite cluster runs within Kubernetes, but applications are outside of it

Tags: c#, kubernetes, ignite

Is there a way to connect C# Thick Client running in the Windows Machine outside of the Kubernetes with Apache Ignite Cluster nodes are present in the Kubernetes.

Below specified article says it is not possible but this article was written in 2020. We are looking for Scenario-3 from below article
https://dzone.com/articles/apache-ignite-on-kubernetes-things-to-know-about
I hope there might some enhancements for Scenario-3.

We dont want convert our C# Thick client to Thin Client as we are using Data Streamer to insert data in bulk and same functionality is not available with Thin Client.

Comment: The .net thin client does have the data streamer API.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Thanks for providing your input, yes, .net thin client does not have the data stream, but is there is a way to connect thick client outside of kuberne cluster and ignite in Kubernet Cluster?

Comment: That's the opposite of what I said! The .net thin-client _does_ have the data streamer API. See the release notes for [2.11](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.11.0/release_notes.html).

Comment: @StephenDarlington : Thanks for sharing the info; In thick client, we can add bulk data with DataStreamer. But In thin client, only one value can be added with DataStreamer. We are looking for Bulk data update using Thin Client. And

Comment: @StephenDarlington : Thanks for sharing the info;  Is it possible to connect using Thick Client that is deployed outside of Kubernets Cluster?  As we are looking for Bulk data update using  DataStreamer. Yes, we understand that thin client supports Data Streamer with only 1 Key value pair can be updated at a time that is performance issue

Comment: @Rameish `IDataStreamerClient.Add` adds data to an internal buffer. There is no performance issue, just call it in a loop. See more details in the docs: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Datastream.IDataStreamerClient-2.html#Apache_Ignite_Core_Client_Datastream_IDataStreamerClient_2_Add__0__1_ .  Thin and thick streamer have similar performance in right conditions: https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Whats-New-In-Ignite-Net-2.11/

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn Thanks for sharing important info and Performance aspects as well. Any suggestion on Connectivity aspect for following deployment I.e Thick Client outside of Cluster and Ignite in Kubernet Cluster.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn We do not find the AllowOverwrite, AutoFlushFrequency parameters in IDataStreamerClient comparing to IDataStreamer. Is there any alternate way to achieve this with IDataStreamerClient? Especially AllowOverwrite...

Comment: @Rameish replied in a separate answer

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation here would be to use the thin-client. The .net thin-client does have the data streamer API.

There is no straight-forward way to connect a thick-client node from outside Kubernetes to a cluster inside it.

Answer (score 1):

To address important points from the comments section:

> we are looking for Bulk data update using DataStreamer
> thin client supports Data Streamer with only 1 Key value pair can be updated at a time that is performance issue

`IDataStreamerClient.Add` adds data to an internal buffer, it does not send entries one by one over the network. There is no performance issue with calling `Add` in a loop. Thin and thick data streamers [demonstrate similar performance](https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Whats-New-In-Ignite-Net-2.11/).

See the [API docs](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Datastream.IDataStreamerClient-2.html#Apache_Ignite_Core_Client_Datastream_IDataStreamerClient_2_Add__0__1_) for more details.

> We do not find the AllowOverwrite, AutoFlushFrequency parameters in IDataStreamerClient comparing to IDataStreamer

See [DataStreamerClientOptions](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Datastream.DataStreamerClientOptions.html)

```cs
var options = new DataStreamerClientOptions
{
    SkipStore = true,
    AllowOverwrite = true,
    AutoFlushInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    PerNodeBufferSize = 1024,
    PerNodeParallelOperations = Environment.ProcessorCount 
};

using (var streamer = Client.GetDataStreamer<int, int>(cacheName, options))
{
    foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(1, 300))
    {
        streamer.Add(x, -x);
    }
}
```